# Adding pagination (table paging) to Google visualization table

Tags: javascript, database, pagination, google-visualization

I am looking to add pagination to my Google visualization table. I have followed the guide and have the code below. I can't figure out why it's not working... can anyone see anything wrong? The pagination part is at the bottom.

Also, as a longer term project, if possible, I'd be looking to have each page as a separate webpage rather than all on the same URL... anyone know a why to implement this?

Javascript code:

```
function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Nationality');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Age');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Foot');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Position');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Attack');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Control');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dribbling');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Low Pass');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Lofted Pass');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Finishing');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Place Kicking');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Controlled Spin');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Heading');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Defence');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ball Winning');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Kicking Power');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Explosive Power');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Body Balance');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Jump');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Goalkeeping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Saving');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tenacity');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Stamina');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Form');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Injury Resistance');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weak Foot Usage');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weak Foot Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Overall Rating');
    data.addRows([
        ['RONALDO','REAL MADRID','PORTUGAL',187,80,28,'Right','LWF',94,90,95,83,87,92,93,85,97,48,49,96,87,87,90,89,50,50,74,78,5,3,5,7,99],
['MESSI','BARCELONA','ARGENTINA',169,67,26,'Left','SS',94,93,98,84,81,99,87,86,74,53,48,80,82,98,83,74,50,50,76,76,6,3,4,6,99],
['INIESTA','BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,65,29,'Right','CMF',86,98,97,94,86,83,72,82,64,67,49,77,78,87,75,63,50,50,78,88,6,2,6,8,98],
['BUFFON','JUVENTUS F.C.','ITALY',191,83,35,'Right','GK',42,60,62,62,63,45,45,45,55,41,45,78,73,75,87,86,96,98,82,62,7,2,4,4,97],
['XAVI','BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,68,33,'Right','CMF',82,95,89,98,90,73,80,82,67,71,58,76,74,83,74,72,50,50,80,88,8,2,4,5,97],
['PIRLO','JUVENTUS F.C.','ITALY',177,68,34,'Right','DMF',83,93,88,92,97,76,96,95,66,72,58,80,74,76,74,65,50,50,79,82,7,2,7,7,96],
['AGUERO','MAN BLUE','ARGENTINA',175,70,25,'Right','CF',90,88,90,77,73,92,73,72,82,49,47,83,90,90,85,94,50,50,74,83,7,3,5,5,96],
['IBRAHIMOVIC','PARIS SAINT-GERMAIN','SWEDEN',194,94,31,'Right','CF',91,93,96,88,87,87,81,79,76,47,52,93,78,73,98,78,50,50,78,76,5,2,5,6,95],
['VAN PERSIE','MANCHESTER UNITED','NETHERLANDS',183,71,30,'Left','CF',91,89,87,85,84,95,80,90,75,52,46,89,82,82,82,74,50,50,75,77,6,2,5,7,95],
['CAVANI','PARIS SAINT-GERMAIN','URUGUAY',184,74,26,'Right','CF',94,83,83,76,76,94,84,78,90,66,52,85,85,81,86,90,50,50,86,93,7,3,6,4,95],
['FALCAO','AS MONACO FC','COLOMBIA',177,72,27,'Right','CF',94,82,81,79,77,98,75,74,97,55,44,81,80,84,76,86,50,50,77,78,6,3,5,6,95],
['CASILLAS','REAL MADRID','SPAIN',185,84,32,'Left','GK',40,47,56,58,59,45,45,45,55,45,44,75,75,79,81,85,97,95,90,60,7,3,4,4,95],
['NEUER','BAYERN MÜNCHEN','GERMANY',193,92,27,'Right','GK',40,62,62,63,66,45,45,45,55,45,42,86,72,75,86,79,97,94,85,60,7,3,3,4,94],
['ROONEY','MANCHESTER UNITED','ENGLAND',176,86,27,'Right','CF',90,86,84,85,84,93,76,80,78,63,55,89,83,83,91,76,50,50,90,90,6,3,5,6,94],
['SUÁREZ','MERSEYSIDE RED','URUGUAY',181,81,26,'Right','CF',93,83,88,82,78,93,78,77,68,57,49,85,83,85,84,74,50,50,65,81,4,3,4,5,94],
['JÚLIO CÉSAR','FREE','BRAZIL',186,79,34,'Left','GK',47,67,66,64,66,50,54,56,55,41,45,78,72,75,83,82,94,96,75,60,6,3,4,4,94],
['CESC FABREGAS','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',179,75,26,'Right','CMF',84,91,87,92,85,85,77,80,70,73,51,80,76,82,75,73,50,50,82,92,6,2,6,7,93],
['RONALDINHO','ATLÉTICO MINEIRO','BRAZIL',182,80,33,'Right','AMF',81,92,94,92,88,84,86,89,78,47,46,81,80,76,81,82,50,50,75,74,4,2,5,6,93],
['SILVA','MAN BLUE','SPAIN',170,67,27,'Left','AMF',85,92,91,93,85,81,76,77,62,60,46,77,80,90,74,75,50,50,72,80,6,2,3,3,93],
['VIDIC','MANCHESTER UNITED','SERBIA',189,84,31,'Right','CB',65,71,69,72,70,61,62,61,92,91,87,75,74,71,92,86,50,50,86,79,6,2,4,4,93],
['HANDANOVIC','INTER','SLOVENIA',193,89,29,'Right','GK',40,45,48,46,49,45,45,45,55,43,41,76,70,73,86,70,95,95,75,65,7,3,5,5,93],
['VALDÉS','FBARCELONA','SPAIN',183,78,31,'Right','GK',41,62,60,63,64,45,50,50,55,45,40,81,75,82,84,84,95,92,83,60,7,3,3,4,92],
['CECH','LONDON FC','CZECH REPUBLIC',197,92,31,'Left','GK',40,63,52,56,57,45,45,45,55,45,43,85,67,70,88,80,92,95,78,60,7,2,4,4,92],
['FREY','GENOA CFC','FRANCE',189,85,33,'Right','GK',41,48,52,55,52,45,45,45,55,40,46,75,67,68,86,82,95,92,76,60,7,2,3,3,92],
['NEYMAR','FBARCELONA','BRAZIL',174,64,21,'Right','SS',82,93,98,81,80,84,85,82,65,50,43,75,83,93,73,83,50,50,65,78,5,2,5,6,92],
['THIAGO SILVA','PARIS SAINT-GERMAIN','BRAZIL',183,79,29,'Right','CB',73,78,83,82,84,65,75,66,81,94,85,85,83,83,87,92,50,50,83,81,6,3,5,5,92],
['DI NATALE','UDINESE CALCIO','ITALY',170,70,35,'Right','CF',88,87,84,83,85,95,82,85,71,50,41,75,79,87,72,72,50,50,84,75,7,2,5,6,92],
['MILITO','INTER','ARGENTINA',183,78,34,'Right','CF',91,85,83,77,74,92,70,72,78,57,47,78,77,79,81,78,50,50,80,79,6,2,6,7,92],
['TERRY','LONDON FC','ENGLAND',187,90,32,'Right','CB',67,72,72,78,77,64,58,56,90,90,93,80,71,67,91,82,50,55,91,77,4,2,6,7,92],
['KOMPANY','MAN BLUE','BELGIUM',191,91,27,'Right','CB',71,78,78,78,81,63,63,63,82,90,92,81,79,74,92,84,50,50,87,80,7,1,5,5,92],
['CHIELLINI','JUVENTUS F.C.','ITALY',186,76,29,'Left','CB',71,73,73,70,72,66,65,70,79,91,90,83,83,76,89,87,50,50,86,82,7,2,4,4,92],
['ROBBEN','BAYERN MÜNCHEN','NETHERLANDS',180,80,29,'Left','RMF',84,87,94,80,83,84,78,80,70,54,46,85,92,88,78,73,50,50,65,76,4,1,4,4,92]
    ]);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.querySelector('#dashboard'));

    var stringFilter1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'string_filter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0
        }
    });

    var stringFilter2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'position',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 7
        }
    });

    var numberRangeFilter1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'numnber_range_filter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 5,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100,
            ui: {
                label: 'Overall Rating'
            }
        }
    });

    var numberRangeFilter2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'height',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 3,
            minValue: 160,
            maxValue: 210,
            ui: {
                label: 'Height'
            }
        }
    });

    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Table',
        containerId: 'table_div',
        options: {
            showRowNumber: true
        }
    });

    dashboard.bind([stringFilter1, stringFilter2, numberRangeFilter1, numberRangeFilter2], [table]);
    dashboard.draw(data);

   options['page'] = 'enable';
  options['pageSize'] = 20;
  options['pagingSymbols'] = {prev: 'prev', next: 'next'};
  options['pagingButtonsConfiguration'] = 'auto';
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: drawTable});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the options to enable paging after drawing the table, which is why it doesn't work.  Set those options in the table's ChartWrapper instead, and it will work:

```
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_div',
    options: {
        showRowNumber: true,
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 20,
        pagingSymbols: {
            prev: 'prev',
            next: 'next'
        },
        pagingButtonsConfiguration: 'auto'
    }
});
```

IMO< forcing a page reload or forcing the user to navigate to a new page is not a good idea for handing table pagination, but you can do it if you really want to.  You just need to keep track of where your user is in the data set and serve up the appropriate data when the page is refreshed or the new page is visited.

I would suggest, however, that you investigate implementing server-side paging via AJAX calls.  Set up a script or servlet that hands out data in pieces, and an AJAX function on the client-side that calls the server for the next piece of data (it could be one page, 5 pages, 100 pages, whatever is most convenient for your application), and fills in the table piece-by-piece.

Answer (score -1):

```
D3 table with pagination. Check this fiddle below.
var tableChartWithPagination = function(inputData, divName) {
var wd = 700;
var ht = 550;
var keys = new Array();
// no. of rows per page
var pageSize = 4;
var currentPage = 1;
var totalPages = getTotalPages();
...
```

[D3 table with pagination.](http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilb/o0rq4aza/)
    cheers.